# Cann't access Thread property(a List<Events) instantiated in servletcontext(i.e. application scope) using struts tags

Tags: scope, servletcontextlistener, struts-tags

Here is my AvailLableEvents Thread Code:

```
    package eventmanagement.util;

    import java.util.List;

    import eventmanagers.Events;

    public class AvailableEvents extends Thread{

    private List<Events>availableEventsList=null;

    public List<Events> getAvailablEventsList() {
      return availableEventsList;
    }
    public void setAvailableEventsList(List<Events> availableEventsList) {
       this.availableEventsList = availableEventsList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(true){
        this.availableEventsList=Events.getAvailableEvents();

         //System.out.println("Executing");
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1000*60*30);//sleep for 30 minutes
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }

    }
```

I created a ServletContextListener Which starts the AvailableEvents Thread:

```
    package eventmanagement.util;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

    public class EventManagementServletContextListener implements
        ServletContextListener {



    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {


    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

         AvailableEvents currentevents=new AvailableEvents();
    currentevents.start();

    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("EVENTS", currentevents);


    }

    }
```

Here is Listener's Config in web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
          eventmanagement.util.EventManagementServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Struts tags for accessing the ListavailableEvents in my JSP:

```
    <s:set name="curEventsThread" value="#application['EVENTS']"></s:set>
        <s:set name="curEventsList" value="#curEventsThread.availableEventsList"/>
        <s:iterator value="#curEventsList">
        <s:property value="eventtitle"/>
    </s:iterator>
```

eventtitle is instance variable of class Events

I'm able to get desired values by using this code in any Subclass of ActionSupport:

```
     AvailableEvents ae=(AvailableEvents)ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("EVENTS");
    List<Events>ce=ae.getAvailablEventsList();

    for(Events e:ce){
        System.out.println(e.getEventtitle());
    }
```

How to do this in Struts tags
Thanks in Advance for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got Results using struts tags in all my JSP:

```
<s:set name="availEvents" value="#application['EVENTS']"/>
    <s:set name="mylist" value="#availEvents.getAvailableEventsList()"/>
      <s:iterator value="mylist">
        <s:property value="eventtitle"/><br/>
      </s:iterator>
```